# Enabling Nvidia Graphics on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, nvidia

I've been struggling this for quite some time and it's come to a point where looking at my screen hurts my eyes because I think my video driver settings are all messed up.

**Additional Drivers** says I have NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver but they are "not currently in use" (Screen shot below).  How the heck do I put them to use??

[image]

NVIDIA X server settings says that I don't have NVIDIA X drivers and to edit nvidia-xconfig (screen shot below).  I did that and all hell broke lose, my system would only start in terminal mode so I had to go to recovery mode and put X setting back to default.

[image]

Please tell me a way of how to active my nvidia driver settings?

**Update**

My Video card is: EVGA 512-P3-1301-KR GeForce 8400 GS 512MB 32-bit DDR3 PCI Express 2.0 x16 HDCP Ready Low Profile Video Card

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814130608

I re-installed the nvidia-current driver and some changes happened.

- I still have "not in use"
- But I can launch nvidia-settings from terminal so I guess it actually is installed now
- Now I cant see my second monitor...its just blank screen
- Clicking on minimize and maximize buttons has not effect
- Monitor that does turn on does not show top and bottom bars where time and tasks are.

Comment: What is your video-card  or graphics card?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nvidia driver activated but not in use (gtx280)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44653/nvidia-driver-activated-but-not-in-use-gtx280)

Comment: Removing the driver and reinstalling usually fixes it for me. Try: sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current" and then "sudo apt-get install nvidia-current". Then restart.

Comment: @Alin I re-installed and that seems to have actually installed the driver even though it says "not in use" now. However, now I cant see my second monitor display and clicking on minimize maximize buttons has no effect what so ever

Comment: @belacqua I've updated the question with my graphics card information.

Comment: I had similar issues with a 7300GS. Try the steps in the linked question.  You should be able to get this resolved ; add your troubleshooting steps to your question (or a new one, if it diverges from the existing 'possible duplicate' question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you start "nvidia-settings" in terminal? If yes, your nvidia driver is active and in use.

There is a bug in jockey ("Additional Drivers"). It allways says "not in use". If your driver works, don't care what jockey says.

Comment: I re-installed this driver and even now it says "not in use" but you are right. Now I can launch nvidia-settings from terminal, however, now there are new problems. My second monitor does not turn on and monitor that does turn on does not show the top and bottom launch bars and also clicking on minimize and maximize buttons has no effect

Comment: @Omni You might want to open this as a new question.