# How to install a new graphic card without Xserver

Tags: nvidia, xorg, gpu

I'v bought a new graphic card and installed it on my pc.
Now - ubuntu won't load, all I get is a command line terminal at the end.
I've tried to type startx and got this error:

NVIDIA(0): The NVIDIA GPU at PCI:2:0:0 in not supported by the 173.14.30 NVIDIA driver
NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA graphics device.
Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.

Now what do I do? how can I get X up and running again?

Comment: Apparently a duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61895/how-to-stop-booting-into-terminal-mode 

The answer there solved my problem

    sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
    sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Answer (score 2):

This question was solved by the OP:

> Apparently a duplicate of: [askubuntu.com/questions/61895/…](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61895/how-to-stop-booting-into-terminal-mode)
>
> The answer there solved my problem `sudo apt-get purge nvidia* sudo rm
>   /etc/X11/xorg.conf`